# Python unittest : how to specify custom equality predicate?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

This could be an easy question; I'd like to use a custom equality operator in a Python `unittest` test case. So for instance, supposing I want to test a "number-to-string" function, and I want to perform a case-insensitive string comparison.

Here's what I'd like to write:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFoo(self):
        self.assertCheck(ci_string_eq,i2s(24),"Twenty-Four")
```

The problem is that `assertCheck` isn't a thing.

Some obvious workarounds:

- use assertTrue; the problem is that then a test case failure becomes opaque
  and unhelpful; "expected True, got False". Bleah.
- dig into unittest and extend it myself; well, I'm hoping to avoid that :)

I hope I'm missing something obvious?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: some have suggested that I override `__eq__`. This is not what I want. Specifically, the `__eq__` method is used by clients of my code, to determine
whether two objects should be considered "the same" (cf. "extensional equality").
For the purposes of testing, though, I want to test using a different predicate.
So overriding `__eq__` does not solve my problem.

Comment: You can take an OOP approach and wrap the unit under test into a class and then override the `__eq__` method to behave like you want. Then you test only the `__eq__` method. Separate your concerns.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified this; I explicitly *don't* want that; the __eq__ method is for extensional equality, and I want to test inside the module. Let me edit to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that there isn't any complicated wiring to make a custom assertion with your own rules. Just do the comparison, gather any helpful information, then call [`fail(msg)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail) if needed. That will take care of any reporting you need.

Of course, I'm so lazy that I don't even like to gather the helpful information. What I often find useful is to strip out the irrelevant stuff from both the expected and the actual data, then use the regular `assertEquals(expected, actual)`.

Here's an example of both techniques, plus a bonus one that uses [`longMessage`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage) to include context:

```
# file scratch.py

from unittest import TestCase
import sys

def convert(i):
    results = 'ONE TOO THREE'.split()
    return results[i-1]


class FooTest(TestCase):
    def assertResultEqual(self, expected, actual):
        expected_lower = expected.lower()
        actual_lower = actual.lower()
        if expected_lower != actual_lower:
            self.fail('Results did not match: {!r}, {!r}, comparing {!r}, {!r}'.format(
                expected,
                actual,
                expected_lower,
                actual_lower))

    def assertLazyResultEqual(self, expected, actual):
        self.assertEqual(expected.lower(), actual.lower())

    def assertLongLazyResultEqual(self, expected, actual):
        self.longMessage = True
        self.assertEqual(expected.lower(),
                         actual.lower(),
                         'originals: {!r}, {!r}'.format(expected, actual))

    def test_good_convert(self):
        expected = 'One'

        s = convert(1)

        self.assertResultEqual(expected, s)
        self.assertLazyResultEqual(expected, s)
        self.assertLongLazyResultEqual(expected, s)

    def test_bad_convert(self):
        expected = 'Two'

        s = convert(2)

        self.assertResultEqual(expected, s)

    def test_lazy_bad_convert(self):
        expected = 'Two'

        s = convert(2)

        self.assertLazyResultEqual(expected, s)

    def test_long_lazy_bad_convert(self):
        expected = 'Two'

        s = convert(2)

        self.assertLongLazyResultEqual(expected, s)
```

That generates the following output, including context and reports of pass and failure counts.

```
$ python -m unittest scratch
F.FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_bad_convert (scratch.FooTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 43, in test_bad_convert
    self.assertResultEqual(expected, s)
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 18, in assertResultEqual
    actual_lower))
AssertionError: Results did not match: 'Two', 'TOO', comparing 'two', 'too'

======================================================================
FAIL: test_lazy_bad_convert (scratch.FooTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 50, in test_lazy_bad_convert
    self.assertLazyResultEqual(expected, s)
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 21, in assertLazyResultEqual
    self.assertEqual(expected.lower(), actual.lower())
AssertionError: 'two' != 'too'
- two
?  ^
+ too
?  ^


======================================================================
FAIL: test_long_lazy_bad_convert (scratch.FooTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 57, in test_long_lazy_bad_convert
    self.assertLongLazyResultEqual(expected, s)
  File "/home/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 27, in assertLongLazyResultEqual
    'originals: {!r}, {!r}'.format(expected, actual))
AssertionError: 'two' != 'too'
- two
?  ^
+ too
?  ^
 : originals: 'Two', 'TOO'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=3)
```

If the custom comparison applies to a specific class, then you can [add a custom equality operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc) for that class. If you do that in your `setUp()` method, then all the test methods can just call `assertEquals()` with that class, and your custom comparison will be called.

Comment: Say, that *is* good news. In fact, you did the thing that I didn't want to do! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The built in unittest module has a specific method for this called `addTypeEqualityFunc`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc).
You just have to write your equality function and pass it and simply use the `assertEqual` method as usual.

Comment: Interesting. Part of me is appalled by certain aspects of this solution, but I think that for my use case (teaching first-year students) it might be perfect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the full list of supported assertions in Python 3.6's `unittest` module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods)

As you can see, there is no assertion that takes a custom predicate to evaluate, but you can get a more helpful error message by passing a *custom error message* to your assertion method through the `msg` argument.

For instance:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def testFoo(self):
    self.assertEqual(i2s(24),"Twenty-Four",msg="i2s(24) should be 'Twenty-Four'")
```

If that is not enough for you, you don't really need to go around digging into `unittest`: You could define a class that extends `unittest`'s TestCase with the methods you need, i.e.:

```
class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def assertCheck(self):
    ...
```

And then you would define your tests as:

```
class MyTest(CustomTestCase):
  def testFoo(self):
    self.assertCheck(...)
```

Comment: In re: first solution: the problem with this is that I don't want to use the existing equality predicate; that's the point of my question. In re: second solution: well, sure, but then I need to dig around in the source of unittest to figure how to hook into the success/failure count, print out results, etc. etc. That's what I said I'm hoping to avoid.  Thanks though!

Comment: I believe the Pythonic way to go about this would be to implement custom ````__eq__```` and ````__ne__```` methods for your class instead of doing it as part of the test. That way, you can make "equality" mean whatever you like.

Comment: In that case, just inside your test module you could use a class that extends the class you're trying to test and only overrides ````__eq__```` and ````__ne__````. That way, you get module-local behavior without changing your class.

It's not the  most elegant solution ever, but it works.

Comment: How would you coerce the objects of the class-to-be-tested to be objects of the extended class?

Comment: You could either write an initializer which would take an object of the class-to-be-tested and produce an object of the extended class with the same values, or (and just now I think of this) you could monkey-patch the class within your unit test module like this:

    `YourClass.__eq__ = new_eq_method`
    `YourClass.__ne__ = new_ne_method`

Answer (score 0):

You can override `__eq__` method of return value class without convoluting the original unit by subclassing it.

```
class Helper(FooReturnValueClass):

  def __init__(self, obj=None, **kwargs):
     self.obj = obj
     # any other attrs
     # probably good idea to skip calling super

  def __eq__(self, other):
    # logic

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testFoo(self):
      expect = self.Helper(...)
      actual = ClassUnderTest.foo(...)
      self.assertEqual(expect, foo) # Order is important
```